# Deploying a microservice with its own database: how to guarantee replication and reliability?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud, microservices, database-administration

I am building an application to be deployed in a cloud environment.
I am using Kubernetes with Docker.

My image contains two containers: one for the application, and another with Postgres DBMS (including its own database that is stored through a persistent volume claim).

I did it like this because this way I could scale my application linearly, as my main requirement is to be able to scale it like that.

So when I scale my deployment, it will look more or less like the draw bellow (having N pods of my application):
[image]

I have done performance tests into this architecture, and it works very well for my needs, and it scales as I needed too.

However, I am worried about the data replication and its reliability.

So here are my questions:

1. How to do replication with this type of architecture? Is there a way in which Kubernetes takes care of it through a specific storage class? What is the best approach?
2. In general, what is a DBA expectation when looking into this architecture? Is it acceptable as I may end up with too many databases?

Comment: Why are you deploying the DB in the same pod instead of having DB pods separate from the application pods?

Comment: Because the idea is that they have their own database to make it scale better. If I scale the application only, then my database become a bottleneck.

Comment: How does it work if you scale up by introducing a new instance of the service or scale down by reducing the number of instances.  What happens to the data you already saved? Who serves them after instance gone?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres scaling cannot be performed as you suggested and persistent volumes cannot be mounted in read/write mode in multiple pods ([with a few exceptions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes))

To scale Postgres you can consider [CrunchyData](https://github.com/CrunchyData/postgres-operator)

More over, decoupling the application layer from the DB, has many benefits, including the granular control of the scaling policies upon each layer.

*PS: Nice diagram. It makes the question very intelligible.*

Comment: I have already tested it, and it worked fine. But for simplicity I tested it with HostPath.

Comment: Two independent Postgres instances, happily writing to their /var/lib/postgresql/data, being unaware that behind the scenes, the other instance is writing to the same volume / HostPath?

Comment: We can map them to write into different mount points. For Example: 
/data/app-001
/data/app-002
so on ...

Comment: I don't get it. How do the DBs synchronize? Suppose one user visits your app, he sings-up on PodA. Later he comes back, but the application is served from PodB this time. How will PodB be aware that he is a registered user if his username/pass were stored on PostgresA://data/app-001 which is not present in PostgresB://data/app-002

Comment: It is sharded by the id, so I know where things are. Of course I have something in front of it that is smart enough to find what it needs. But this is not the escope of the question though.